# Correct place to delete dynamic objects

Tags: object-oriented-design

There is a software component `Processor` that processes objects `Item` in a dedicated thread. `Item` may be processed multiple times (more specifically, it's a timer object).

One of the fields of `Item` is a pointer to `BaseObject`. So all derivative classes of `BaseObject` (for example `DerivedObject`) can reside in `Item`. `Item` instances are created in some parts of code like `SomeFunction()` and added to the processing queue of `Processor`.

```
// Base class of objects that are passed around
class BaseObject {}

class DerivedObject : public BaseClass {}

// Unit of work
class Item {
    public:
        BaseObject * obj;
}

class Processor {
    std::vector<Item> items;
public:
    void AddItem(Item item);

    // Run in another thread and process items
    void Work() {
        ...
        SomeCallback(item.obj);
        ...
    }
}

Processor processor; // There is a single instance of the processor

void SomeFunction() {
    DerivedObject * dObject = new DerivedObject();
    Item item;
    item.obj = dObject;
    processor::AddItem(item);
}
```

**Questions:**

1) When and where should I delete `dObject`?

2) Is it a good approach to copy the content of `dObject` while adding it to `Item`?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: 1) Never. Nor should you use `new` to allocate one. Instead `Item::obj` should be a `std::unique_ptr<BaseObject>`. Then the lifetime of the `Item` controls the lifetime of the `DerivedObject`, and you still have polymorphism

Comment: @Caleth Good. Make it an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Never. Nor should you use new to allocate one. Instead Item::obj should be a std::unique_ptr. Then the lifetime of the Item controls the lifetime of the DerivedObject, and you still have polymorphism

```
// Unit of work
class Item {
    public:
        // move an existing obj 
        Item(std::unique_ptr<BaseObject>&& obj) : obj(obj) {}
}

// helper function
template <typename Derived, typename ... Args>
Item make_item(Args ... args)
{ return Item(std::make_unique<Derived>(args...)); }

class Processor {
    std::vector<Item> items;
public:
    void AddItem(Item&& item);

    // Run in another thread and process items
    void Work() {
        ...
        SomeCallback(item.obj.get());
        SomeOtherCallback(*item.obj);
        ...
    }
}

void SomeFunction() {
    std::unique_ptr<BaseObject> item = std::make_unique<DerivedObject>(); // covariant assign
    processor::AddItem(std::move(item)); // move the item in
    processor::AddItem(Item(std::make_unique<DerivedObject>())); // also moves in, but from a temporary
    processor::AddItem(make_item<DerivedObject>()); // construct in place with template
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Would you mind to provide a code snippet that illustrates this idea?

Comment: `Item<DerivedObject>()` is not valid syntax, since `Item` is not a template. You cannot pass explicit template arguments to a constructor.